# Strange error with every GUI program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, scsi

```
Unable to open SCSI controller 0:[\] , error code: 0x5
Unable to open SCSI controller 1:[\] , error code: 0x5
```

In almost **every** program I write with a GUI, these two errors appear when the program is done executing. It just randomly started and I don't think I did anything to make it like this. What is wrong?

Comment: Does it happen with plain javac? If so, could you please post the [minimal, self-contained, compiling amount of code](http://sscce.org) that triggers the problem?

Comment: `class BadThing { public static void main(String[] args) { new javax.swing.JFrame(); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Did you try vary IDEs. If you use Eclipse check out NetBeans(just onl to check, I prefer Eclipse), it may help.